# Angular regex and input type

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, validation

If I use `type='text'` for input: `ng-pattern` **works** and `ng-max` validation **doesn't work**;

If I use `type='number'` for input: `ng-pattern` **doesn't work** and `ng-max` validation **works**; (I can enter unlimited count of zeroes at the begining and in the end)

Example:

```
<input name="input" type="number" placeholder="0.00"
      data-ng-model="example.value"
      data-ng-max="100"
      data-ng-pattern="/^0(\.\d{1,2})?$|^[1-9]\d{0,14}(\.\d{1,2})?$/"
      data-ng-required="true"/>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/hv3qrTZzBy8RlPGT8Snv?p=preview

What is the recipe for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this Plunker and see if it works now.
http://plnkr.co/edit/r6FiR5ZSnnDpcJW2893U?p=preview

```
 <input
    name="input"
    type="number"
    placeholder="0.00"
    data-ng-model="example.value"
    max="100"
    data-ng-pattern="/^0(\.\d{1,2})?$|^[1-9]\d{0,14}(\.\d{1,2})?$/"
    data-ng-required="true"/>
```

It was a really small change, but sometimes that's all it takes. :)

According to the official documentation you should you [max="string"] instead of "ng-max".

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D

Comment: Unfortunately it still allow enter 0000012 which should not be. If you will change type to 'text' it will be not allowed. =(